# How do i get c# to write quotation marks when declaring a string?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, remote-access

so i am writing a program that can send commands to Command Promt and i need to declare a string that has my command in. However my command includes quotation marks. Here is what it currently reads. As you can see, in my variables it starts creating a new string and i just need to know how to make it into just one string.

```
strCmdText= "reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", strCmdText);
```

Comment: escape them with \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `\"`

```
strCmdText= "reg add \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f";
```

Comment: thanks worked great!

Comment: you're also going to need to escape the backslashes in the path you are using. Use '\\' for every '\' , the forward slashes are fine and don't need to be escaped